# How to prove that $(10n+2)!$ is divisible by $(10n+4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics, factorial

I would like to know how one can prove that $(10n+2)!$ is divisible by $(10n+4)$ for natural $n > 0$. I tried to do this using induction but I've got stuck because I couldn't simplify the expression.

I first proved that it holds for $n = 1$.
$$\frac{(10\cdot1+2)!}{(10\cdot1+4)}=\frac{12!}{14}=34214400$$
I then assumed that it's true for n.
$$(10\cdot n+2)!=k(10\cdot4)$$ where k is a natural number.

I then tried to prove that this is true for n+1 using the previous assumption.

I got stuck here because I couldn't prove that $(10n+12)!$ is divisible by $(10n+14)$.

I would very much appreciate your help , thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Hint** $\ 10n\!+\!4\, =\, 2(5n\!+\!2)\ $ and $\,2\neq 5n\!+\!2\,$ are both $< 10n\!+\!2\ $ for $\ n> 0\,$ so occur in $(10n\!+\!2)!$

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand.